# Error returning a pair in cpp

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, binary-tree

I have the following code:

```
 return new std::pair<BST<Data>::iterator(cursor), true>;
```

This results in the following errors:

> could not convert '(operator new(4u), (, ((int*))))' from 'int*' to 'std::pair, bool>'
>   type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template struct std::pair'

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Try `std::make_pair` without the `new` and with a required boolean.

Comment: You sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the `new` (don't use new unless you have to) and `return`, in order to construct a `pair`, use either the mentioned `make_pair()` function or invoke the constructor like this: `pair<T1, T2>(v1, v2)`. You were mixing up the type (`pair<T1, T2>`) with the values to init that type's instance (`v1, v2`).

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to return? A pair by value or really a pointer to a new object-pair? It could be useful to see the return type in the declaration of your function to know your intentions.

If you are trying to return a pair you better use:

```
template <class T1,class T2>
  pair<T1,T2> make_pair (T1 x, T2 y)
  {
    return ( pair<T1,T2>(x,y) );
  }
```

That is, something like:

```
return  std::make_pair ( BST<Data>::iterator(cursor),  true);
```

Or directly:

```
return ( pair<T1,T2>(x,y) );
```

That is, something like:

```
return ( std::pair< BST<Data>::iterator , bool>( cursor, true) );
```

If a pointer to a newly created object if what you want, use:

```
return ( new std::pair< BST<Data>::iterator , bool>( cursor, true) );
```

Now:

> What might be the problem here?

Looking at:

```
template <class T1, class T2> struct pair
{
  typedef T1 first_type;
  typedef T2 second_type;

  T1 first;
  T2 second;
  pair() : first(T1()), second(T2()) {}
  pair(const T1& x, const T2& y) : first(x), second(y) {}
  template <class U, class V>
    pair (const pair<U,V> &p) : first(p.first), second(p.second) { }
};
```

You are trying to instantiate the template using values where we need types `T1` and `T2`.